# How do I localize schedule sting in Android

Tags: android, date, localization, schedule

I have a set of strings like "Friday 8:00am till 6:00pm", how do I localize this string to different languages.

I've tried to use 2 Calendars and SimpleDateFormat, but it doesn't support several values.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateUtils.formatDateRange(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatDateRange(android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20int)) to format time spans.

> Formats a date or a time range according to the local conventions.

Although this will not allow you to localize parts of it yourself, it will provide a consistent user experience *on the device* and is properly localized. You can modify what and how it is displayed by providing various flags.

Comment: the best format it support is Example: "10:00 - 11:00 am, Tue" 
but thank you, I think I found the right point to depart